# c# show 2 columns of database with 28 columns

Tags: c#, mysql, datagridview

I have a database with 28 columns. First column is code, second Name and the rest are values.

```
public void displayData()
{
    con.Open();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM gehaltes", con);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    da.Fill(dt);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
    con.Close();
}
```

With this part of the program I see all the columns in the datagridview. I only want the first 2 but I have to use all the 28 columns if I want to make changes.

Comment: Maybe dont use `SELECT *` ??  Generally a good idea to always specify the columns in the order you want.  You dont need all the columns to make changes *unless* you will be changing something in those other 26 column; which seems less likely if the user cant see/edit them

Comment: @Plutonix I think he means he doesn't want them displayed in the datagridview.

Comment: You should be able to loop over the datagridview's columns and set their visible properties.

Answer (score 1):

Set the `AutoGenerateColumns` property of the DataGridView to false, and add two columns with the property `DataPropertyName` refering to the names that you want to display.

Example:

```
da.Fill(dt);
dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewColumn col = new DataGridViewColumn();
col.Name = "name";
col.HeaderText = "header";
col.DataPropertyName = "yourDBField";

dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);

dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
dataGridView1.AutoResizeColumn(DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.DisplayedCells);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the visible property of individual columns:

```
DataGridView dgv;
// ...
foreach(DataGridViewColumn c in dgv.Columns)
   c.Visible = c.Name == "code" || c.Name == "Name";
```